# Problems with apt mirrors

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I have automated some systems with Ansible. To test if everything is still up to date and working I run my playbooks every night with test-kitchen.

To make things a bit more efficient I dont use `archive.ubuntu.com` but some mirrors which are closer to me.

I tried to use `de.archive.ubuntu.com` but nearly every time apt provisiong fails with some connection problems. If I rerun the command everything works fine. Then I tried to use the apt mirrors autodetect method but then I get errors that some public key is missing `W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192`

In the past I often had problem when choosing some mirror and not the official `archive.ubuntu.com`

Any ideas what's the reason for this? Is this a problem with the mirrors itself?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this method](https://mvogt.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/the-apt-mirror-method/) instead, place the following at the top of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Should cause apt to automatically pick a mirror based on geographical location.